# linking a specific folder from one repository to another

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab

I have two repos:

- https://github.com/Dean-Christian-Armada/3-tier-web-app-web-server
- https://github.com/Dean-Christian-Armada/3-tier-web-app-api

What I want to achieve is my static folder in my *3-tier-web-app-api* will be linked in my *3-tier-web-app-web-server*. So when I add a JPEG image in my static folder on *3-tier-web-app-api* then *3-tier-web-app-web-server* will also update. Very similar to `ln -s` command in linux. Is it possible in Git?

Comment: Have you considered submodules?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I only need one filder to be linked

Answer (score 1):

No, alas. You can use submodules though and create a symlink to the desired folder inside.